# Unit testing in C# of private-static method accepting other private-static method as a delegate parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection, delegates

**What I have:** I have a non-static class containing, among others, two private-static methods: one of them can be passed to another one as a delegate parameter:

```
public class MyClass
{
    ...

    private static string MyMethodToTest(int a, int b, Func<int, int, int> myDelegate)
    {
        return "result is " + myDelegate(a, b);
    }

    private static int MyDelegateMethod(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a + b);
    }
}
```

**What I have to do:** I have to test (with unit testing) the private-static method `MyMethodToTest` with passing to it as the delegate parameter the private-static method `MyDelegateMethod`.

**What I can do:** I know how to test a private-static method, but I do not know how to pass to this method another private-static method of the same class as a delegate parameter.

So, if we assume that the `MyMethodToTest` method has no the third parameter at all, the test method will look like:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
```

...

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTest()
{
    PrivateType privateType = new PrivateType(typeof(MyClass));

    Type[] parameterTypes =
    {
        typeof(int),
        typeof(int)
    };

    object[] parameterValues =
    {
        33,
        22
    };

    string result = (string)privateType.InvokeStatic("MyMethodToTest", parameterTypes, parameterValues);

    Assert.IsTrue(result == "result is 55");
}
```

**My question:** How to test a private-static method passing to it as a delegate parameter another private-static method of the same class?

Comment: why do you want to test one with the other? if you will always pass the MyDelegateMethod to MyMethodToTest, then you should just move that code to MyMethodToTest. if not, then you should be able to test it with any delegate. you can create a Func as an obejct and pass it as a param.

Comment: This is just a simplified picture. In fact, I have many `MyDelegateMethod`-like methods in this class. They are quite simple and are not required to be tested. Most complicated part is the `MyMethodToTest` method and it has to be tested. Apparently, it is possible to write duplicates of the `MyDelegateMethod`-like methods within the test class and pass them as the delegate parameter to the `MyMethodToTest` method (I didn't try), but I would like to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is how it should go

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTest()
{
    PrivateType privateType = new PrivateType(typeof(MyClass));

    var myPrivateDelegateMethod = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("MyDelegateMethod", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);
    var dele = myPrivateDelegateMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int, int>));
    object[] parameterValues =
    {
        33,22,dele
    };
    string result = (string)privateType.InvokeStatic("MyMethodToTest", parameterValues);
    Assert.IsTrue(result == "result is 55");
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! Just one remark: the local variable `parameterTypes` is not used and not required.

Comment: took this line out 
var dele = myPrivateDelegateMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<int, int, int>));
Works well! thanks