# unit testing static method C# program

Tags: c#, unit-testing, private

I want to unit test a static method of my main program:

```
public class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    { ... }
    private static bool TheAnswer(int ans)
    { 
        if (ans == 42)
            return true;
        return false;
     }
}
```

To test it, in my unit test project, I have:

```
var t = new PrivateType(typeof(Program));
bool result = Convert.ToBoolean(t.InvokeStatic("TheAnswer", 42));
Assert.AreEqual(result, true);
```

but this is failing on the call to InvokeStatic with

> An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Attempted to access a missing member.

How can I make this work (can I?)

Stack trace:
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\Projects\myprogram\Test_the_test\bin\Debug\Test_the_test.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\Projects\myprogram\Test_the_test\bin\Debug\myprogram.exe'. Symbols loaded.
Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in mscorlib.dll
'vstest.executionengine.x86.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: UnitTestAdapter: Running test): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\14.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: You should ask yourself if it is logical to test a private method.

Comment: Here's how to [Unit testing of private-static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29384639/).

Comment: See PrivateType.InvokeStatic https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms243976.aspx

Comment: By definition, I believe you should test only public methods. Ask yourself if it makes sense to test a private method. If it does, it is probably a good idea make it public.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels, I did, it is, in this case

Comment: @Oscar, yup, that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: Why not just make it public and call it directly? What is your reasoning?

Comment: The obvious solution is to put it public.

Comment: @Carra Yup, but I'm trying to learn how to Unit Test private methods.  Trying to follow the examples I've found here.

Comment: Why?! Why are you learning to unit test private methods?! You've provided absolutely no reason.

Comment: @mason, personal interest.  Expanding my knowledge

Comment: That is a terrible reason. I could "expand my knowledge" by learning how to put bamboo shoots under my fingernails or shooting myself in the foot. But there's no point to it. As was pointed out to you several times, you should *not* unit test private methods. It doesn't make sense to do that. Learn things that are actually good and useful. Don't learn to do something that's a bad practice.

Comment: @user1443098 Apart for the fact that you should not be testing private members, I am unable to reproduce the problem. Tested the example provided and it works as expected.

Comment: @mason, no need for hostility!  I stumbled across the topic and wanted to explore it, that's all.  FWIW I've never found anything I've learned to be anything but good and useful.  Even it is, "I won't do that again!"

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for trying!  Since I can't make it work, I'll just give it up for now.

Comment: @user1443098 I don't know where you're getting hostility from. I'm simply pointing out to you that you're wasting your time. Yes, things can definitely be a waste of time if your time could have been better spent doing something else.

Comment: Private methods should not be tested; it usually makes no sense.

Comment: @FrederikGheysels so, in your case, you just write them and hope for the best?

Comment: No.  Normally, a private method is used by another part of your application.  When unit-testing, you test functionality that is public to the outside and by doing so, private methods will be tested indirectly.  
When you also test private methods, you kind of expose the internal workings to the outside (your test project), and it will make it harder to refactor internal workings of your component

Comment: I'm not convinced that indirect testing is sufficient.  At the very least, it violates the SRP.  At worst, there is no way to ensure coverage and corner case testing.  My team produces complex code.  to be DRY, many parts of that code is encapsulated in non-trivial private methods.  There is no reason to expose these methods as public and every reason not to do that.  Still, they need to be tested.  Perusing stackoverflow, I can see a diversity of opinions on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    object[] args = new object[1] { 42 };
    bool result = (bool)typeof(Program).InvokeMember(
                    name: "TheAnswer", 
                    invokeAttr: BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                BindingFlags.Static |
                                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                    binder: null, 
                    target: null, 
                    args: args);
Assert.AreEqual(result, true);
```

Comment: Still got a missing member exception